# Some problems with the functions GetCursorPos() and SetCursorPos() in C++

Tags: c++, function, variables, types

I am a new user of C++ and do not know all about types of variables.

I have this code but it doesn't work normally. For normal i mean - after starting cursor must be random moves for -25 to 25 pixel of screen.

Sorry if i provided few information. Ask me i can send what you want. And sorry for my bad English.

````
#include <iostream>
#include "MyForm1.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <playsoundapi.h>
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace std;




// Cursor random moving here :3

int shakecursor() {
    POINT p;

    int __cdecl GetCursorPos(int &p);
    cout <<  p.x << p.y << endl;

    int x_p1;
    int y_p1;

    x_p1 = rand() % 0 -25;
    y_p1 = rand() % 0 -25;

    int x_p = p.x + x_p1;
    int y_p = p.y + y_p1;

    int __cdecl SetCursorPos(int x_p1, int y_p1);


    Sleep(10);
    return 0;
}

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(cli::array<System::String ^> ^args) {





    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    My3yPaB::MyForm mainForm;
    Application::Run(%mainForm);

    bool shaking = true;

    while (shaking = true) {
        shakecursor();

    }

}```
````

Comment: This  int __cdecl SetCursorPos(int x_p1, int y_p1); is not a call expression. It is a function declaration. Do you mean  GetCursorPos(p); and SetCursorPos( x_p, y_p ); ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These

```
int __cdecl GetCursorPos(int &p);
int __cdecl SetCursorPos(int x_p1, int y_p1);
```

are not function calls. they are function declarations.

Instead it seems you mean

```
GetCursorPos( p );
```

and

```
SetCursorPos( x_p, y_p );
```

Comment: i maked all what you sayed but i get 5 new errors:
Ошибка LNK2028 ссылка на неразрешенную лексему (0A00051B) "extern "C" int __cdecl SetCursorPos(int,int)" (?SetCursorPos@@$$J0YAHHH@Z) в функции "int __cdecl shakecursor(void)" (?shakecursor@@$$FYAHXZ) 3yPaB D:\cpp_projects\3yPaB\3yPaB\MyForm.obj 
this is first one

Comment: @disobey They have nothing common with your original error I pointed to. The error you showed means that the compiler can not find the definition of the function.

Answer (score 0):

So i fixed this problem and program doesn't do anything here code:

````
#include <iostream>
#include "MyForm1.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <winuser.h>
#include <Mmsystem.h> 
#include <playsoundapi.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "User32.lib")
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace std;
int shakecursor() {
    POINT p;

    GetCursorPos(&p);
    cout <<  p.x << p.y << endl;

    int x_p1;
    int y_p1;

    x_p1 = rand() % 51 - 25;
    y_p1 = rand() % 51 - 25;

    int x_p = p.x + x_p1;
    int y_p = p.y + y_p1;

    SetCursorPos(x_p, y_p);


    Sleep(10);
    return 0;
}
[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(cli::array<System::String ^> ^args) {
    //PlaySound(L"start.mp3", NULL, NULL);
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    My3yPaB::MyForm mainForm;
    Application::Run(%mainForm);
    bool shaking = true;
    while (shaking = true) {
        shakecursor();      
    }

}```
````